# Timer + display messages + Different time intervals

Tags: c#, timer

How to display some messages on a C# form application with different time intervals with buttons?

Something like:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      label1.Text = "string1";

      [wait 3 seconds]

      label1.Text = "string2";

      [wait 5 sec]

      label1.text="string 3";

      [end]
}
```

Comment: You apparently already know about timers, considering that you've titled and tagged this question "timer". That's exactly what you need here. Have you tried this already?

Comment: You have to use some thread. Current code only display String 3. i think you have to display some message based on process. MY suggestion in Go for timer ( If interval is fixed) or go fo backgroundworker.

Comment: Well yess i tried timer. but as i said me learning. so i got it all messed up. I tried some before posting here :D

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new thread, change the label text, sleep that thread and so on so forth:

```
using System.Threading;
```

---

```
// Somewhere in your Form, for example in Form_Load event:
new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate {
    var d = new setLabelTextDelegate(setLabelText);
    label1.Invoke(d, new object[] { "string 1" });
    Thread.Sleep(3000); // sleep 3 seconds
    label1.Invoke(d, new object[] { "string 2" });
    Thread.Sleep(5000); // sleep 5 seconds
    label1.Invoke(d, new object[] { "string 3" });
})).Start();
```

---

```
private delegate void setLabelTextDelegate(string text);
private void setLabelText(string text)
{
    this.label1.Text = text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a Timer with an interval of X milliseconds and update the UI each Timer Tick. Keep track of the number of Timer Ticks received so you'll know which string to use. After each update has been processed stop the Timer.

Other solutions posted might be wiser, but this one is pretty simple.

Form1 contains a simple Label called Label1 and a button called Button1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        t.Interval = 100;
        t.Tick += new EventHandler(t_Tick);
        t.Start();
    }

    Timer t = new Timer();
    int counter = 0;

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t.Start();
    }

    void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            t.Enabled = false; //Disable timer so we don't start t_Tick when t_Tick is still runnnig

            if (counter == 0)
            {
                label1.Text = "string1";
                t.Interval = 3000;
            }
            if (counter == 1)
            {
                label1.Text = "string2";
                t.Interval = 5000;
            }
            if (counter == 2)
            {
                label1.Text = "string3";
                t.Stop(); //Stop timer
            }
            else
            {
                t.Enabled = true; //Resume timer
            }

            counter++;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Never throw exception from timer..." + ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you :) ... This idea will work. May be this is what i have been looking for :)

Comment: and how to start it all with a click of button ?

Comment: @Ron: put 't.Start();' under the button Click handler.

Comment: i have one more issue. IF i start it with button , then it stops after string 3 , as it should. But but again if i pressing button then its not starting ovr again.

Comment: You'll have to reset the counter.

Answer (score 0):

To do exactly as your pseudo code suggest simply use `Thread.Sleep()` in place of your `[wait x]` lines. Note that it will likely make UI unresponsive for the duration of waiting.

Alternatively you can create a thread that does the same thing but doesn't block the UI thread. The only issue there is that you have to define delegate in UI thread otherwise it wont work.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate()
    {
        label1.Text = "string1";
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        label1.Text = "string2";
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        //etc...
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

      label1.Text = "string1";
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3*1000);
        label1.Text = "string2";
       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5*1000);
        label1.text="string 3";
}
```

Comment: didn't u see what he said. he is new to c# so it's always better start from ground floor. I am not even sure he would understand what rest of people have posted. the important thing is understand what exactly does the Thread.Sleep() method. when he encounters those issues. he can explore much further. ;) cause life will find a way.

Comment: I don't think using `Thread.Sleep()` is starting from the ground floor. You need to understand threading in order to understand what it does, why you should/shouldn't use it, etc.

Comment: I called it relative ground floor.

Comment: Well I do understood what rest have posted.with timers. I have tried to do it all Thread.sleep() before posting here. but then it all got messed . so finally asked here as ground :) thank you sooo much for such good and great responses :) these examples will help me learn more. :) thank you.

Comment: glad to hear that but this is not actually good if you have been looking for a real Timing works. for that use the Timer class

Comment: use the BackgroundWorker control it's much better for threading.

Answer (score 0):

**Thank you sooo much.**

Oh i love  stakoverflow.com
I did something like this.:) 
Thank you all gentle mens :)
Please comment how did i do? I actually wanted it all happen in click of button.

> public partial class mainForm : Form {
>           public mainForm()
>
> Timer myTimer = new Timer();
>
> private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>
> ```
>     {
>        myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(myTimer_Tick);
>        myTimer.Interval = 2000; 
>        myTimer.Start();
>     }
> ```
>
> int counter=0;
>
> ```
>     void myTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>
>         if (counter == 0)
>         {
>             label4.Text = "string1";
>             myTimer.Interval = 2000;
>         }
>         if (counter == 1)
>         {
>             label4.Text = "string2";
>             myTimer.Interval = 2000;
>         }
>         if (counter == 2)
>         {
>             label4.Text = "string3";
>             myTimer.Stop(); 
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             myTimer.Enabled = true; 
>         }
>         counter++;
>       } }
> ```

**I made it all work with valuable examples you all provided . i put it all together and got it working as i wanted. 
Once again Thank you all :)**

Comment: Code optimization suggestions will be hearty welcome :) Me beginner/learner .

Comment: **I made this out of this timer project**

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t_CwMjllysg